# how to register a user with one to many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I don't understand why I am getting the error :
this is my codes

**PlayersConroller**

```
    public function store(Request $request){

        // $games = ModelsGames::findOrFail($request->game_id);
        $roles = ModelsRoles::findOrFail($request->role_id);
        // $states = ModelsStates::findOrFail($request->state_code);
        // dd($states);

        $roles->players()->create([
            // 'role_id' => $request->role_id,
            'game_id' => $request->game_id,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'ign' => $request->ign,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'state_code' => $request->state_code,
        ]);

        return redirect('admin/players');
    }
```

**PlayersModel**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'role_id',
        'game_id',
        'name',
        'ign',
        'address',
        'state_code'
    ];
```

**GamesModel**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'game_name',
    ];

    public function players() {
        return $this->hasMany(Players::class, 'game_id', 'id');
    }
```

**RolesModel**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'role',
    ];

    public function players(){
        return $this->hasMany(Players::class, 'role_id', 'id');
    }
```

**StatesModel**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'state_code',
        'city',
    ];

    public function players(){
        return $this->hasMany(Players::class, 'state_code', 'id');
    }
```

**PlayerMigration**

```
        Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            // $table->unsignedBigInteger('state_code');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('game_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('ign')->unique();
            $table->string('address');

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            // $table->foreign('state_code')->references('state_code')->on('states')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('players', function (Blueprint $table){
            // $table->foreignId('state_code')->constrained()->on('states')->onDelete('cascade');
            // $table->unsignedBigInteger('state_code');
            // $table->foreignId('state_code')->reference('state_code')->constrained()->on('states')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('state_code')->nullable()->constrained('states')->onDelete('cascade');
            // $table->unsignedBigInteger('state_code');
            // $table->foreign('state_code')->references('state_code')->on('states');
        });
```

**statesMigration**

```
        Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('state_code');
            $table->string('city');
        });
```

**RolesMigration**

```
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('role');
        });
```

**GamesMigration**

```
        Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('game_name');
        });
```

In this code I just created a migration for the 3 tables that are connected into 1 table. For the 2 table I use id to create a foreign key using their primary key but the states table i wanted to connect the states table but this time i dont want to use primary key instead i wanted to use the **state_code** column in the table my migration is success with that but when i register a player the error says
**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`players`.`players`, CONSTRAINT `players_state_code_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`state_code`) REFERENCES `states` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
t**
I really dont understand why i am getting the error can anyone help me with that thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the `state_code` you specified actually exists in the `states` table?

Comment: yes i im sure that i have a state_code in the state table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key constraint for the `state_code` column in the players' table references the id column of the states table instead of the `state_code` column. To resolve this issue, you need to modify your migration file for the players' table.

```
Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('state_code'); // Change the column type to unsigned integer
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('game_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('ign')->unique();
    $table->string('address');

    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('state_code')->references('state_code')->on('states')->onDelete('cascade'); // Change the reference column
    $table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Modify the state_code column in the states table migration.

```
Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedInteger('state_code'); // Change the column type to unsignedInteger
    $table->string('city');
});
```

You must also change the relation defined in your StatesModel to reflect using the column `state_code` instead of `id`.

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Players::class, 'state_code', 'state_code');
}
```

Comment: i got an error when i migrate the database says   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referenci
ng column 'state_code' and referenced column 'st
ate_code' in foreign key constraint 'players_sta
te_code_foreign' are incompatible. (Connection: 
mysql, SQL: alter table `players` add constraint
 `players_state_code_foreign` foreign key (`stat
e_code`) references `states` (`state_code`) on d
elete cascade)

Comment: The code is work perfectly but the migration has that error can you explain why i get that error?

Comment: In the players table, state_code is an unsigned integer and in the states table it is an integer. They have to match types.